# New Xamarin.Forms project: emulator is blank

Tags: android, android-emulator, xamarin.forms

I'd hoped a new project would work out of the box, but unfortunately it doesn't.... this is what I have done:

1. Freshly reformatted Windows computer
2. Fresh install of Visual Studio 2015 with *all* the options
3. Create new Xamarin.Forms project
4. Try to run it...

The emulator opens but it is completely blank.  I'd expected it to show the "Welcome to Xamarin Forms!" text from the new project template.

p.s. using the emulator AVD_GalaxyNexus_ToolsForApacheCordova (Android 4.4 - API 19)

Comment: Have you tried with a real device to see if the application is correctly deployed? If so, I would suggest using Genymotion for emulator.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Visual Studio 2015 on Windows I would recommend you use the Microsoft Visual Studio Emulator for Android instead.

If you see the 5" KitKat (4.4) emulator I would choose that or something else similar with a higher API if required.

If you don't see these other emulators, you can download [Visual Studio Emulator for Android](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/) or you might want to do a quick search in Cortana to see if you already have it installed. If it does appear in your search results, open it and you can download the emulators you want and they will appear in your Visual Studio drop down.

Comment: Thanks but the emulator you suggest requires Windows 10.  This old computer can't run 10, it can only run Windows 7.